# my RichTextBox is missing properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, richtextbox

Hope some1 here knows why I am missing these properties....
If I take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx
this definitly shows a property called VerticalContenAlignment - IntelliSense doesn't propose this property and if I just type it, the compiler also rejects it.... The Project is runnign on .NET 4 so it should confirm to the above link where it says these are the .NET 4 characteristics...
Any idea why I am missing these properties?

Thanks for any help!!!

-EDIT: Ok I guess I have the reason:
The link above lists properties for System.Windows.Controls.Richtextbox, I have a System.Windows.Forms.Richtextbox ...How can I combine this now thoug? any why are there 2 different ones? Sorry if its a stupid question - I'm just not getting it right now...

Comment: Nope I'm not...I edited aboev, maybe that helps...

Comment: Regarding Henks comment, you probably should be creating a WPF project instead of a normal Forms project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new component you would like to use is for WPF projects, the standard RichTextBox for Windows forms is another control and you cannot mix them. Either you do not use the new property and you live with what the Windows Forms component offers you or you use a third party component to achieve what you need.

Comment: Ok thanks guys ... sadly WPF is no option for performance reasons and the whole project is non WPF so I'll just have to find a way to bypass the whole thing or live with the ugly alignment :P  Thanks a lot!!